# CSS Transition: Cover Image From Bottom To Top

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is a codepen: https://codepen.io/jon424/pen/XWzGNLe

In this example, if you select the `toggle` button, the image will be covered by another div. The white square will gradually cover the image from the top of the image to the bottom.

I simply want to reverse this effect. I want the white square to cover the image, moving from the bottom of the image to the top.

I’ve tried using a negative value for `max-height` in the `.covered` class, but that wasn’t working. Any idea on how I can go about doing this?

```js
document.querySelector('.child2').classList.add('covered');

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('.child2').classList.toggle('covered');
});
```

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.child2 {
  z-index: 1;
  background: #ffffff;
  transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
  max-height:100%;
}

.covered {
  max-height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<button>Toggle</button>
<div class="parent">
  <img class="child1" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
  <div class="child1 child2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple: change the `top: 0;` attribute in `.child1` to `bottom: 0;`

Answer (score 1):

By adding those lines on `.child2` I am getting I think what you want:

```css
 bottom:0;
 top:unset;
```

Here is the full working example:

```js
document.querySelector(".child2").classList.add("covered");

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.querySelector(".child2").classList.toggle("covered");
});
```

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.child2 {
  z-index: 1;
  background: #ffffff;
  transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
  max-height: 100%;
  bottom:0;
  top:unset;
}

.covered {
  max-height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<button>Toggle</button>
<div class="parent">
  <img class="child1" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
  <div class="child1 child2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do it you can manipulate the `top` of the `child2`:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => { document.querySelector('.child2').classList.toggle('covered');});
```

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.child2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #ffffff;
  transition: top 1s ease-in-out;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.covered {
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<button>Toggle</button>
<div class="parent">
  <img class="child1" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
  <div class="child1 child2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but are you looking for this type of effect, I know CSS solution if this help you.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.parent::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
}

.parent:hover::before {
  height: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.9s ease;
  transition: height 0.9s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img class="child1" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
</div>
</div>
```